# Diferenças de Hoisting entre variáveis e funções

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Porque com variáveis, para se fazer hoisting, é preciso que inicialize a variável antes de chamar, por exemplo:

```js
x = 1; // inicializa
console.log(x); // executando
var x; // declara
```

Mas com funções não é necessário realizar o mesmo processo?

```js
test();

function test() {
    console.log('hello World')
}
```

Entendo que quando compila, as declarações são colocadas em memória do computador, mas não consigo entender porque essa diferença.

Answer (score -2):

é como o hoisting ou *içamento*, *levantamento* funciona.

Na prática, depois que o interpretador lê o script, ele sobe o `var x` do mesmo jeito que ele sobe o `function test() { }`.

A linguagem deixa declarar depois de usar mas na prática as declarações todas ocorreram antes.

É como se o programador fosse espalhando declarações e uso como bem quer mas o interpretador vai catando tudo na ordem certa.

Tem mais detalhes mas o básico é isso.